# Android: findViewById(R.id.listView) is returning null

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a custom layout:

**taskview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity looks like this:

**DaysList.java**

```
public class DaysList extends Activity {

    String []data= {"Wake up", "Take a shit", "Bath", "Feed your belly"};
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);            
    }

    public void showTask(View view){

        listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.task_row, R.id.textView, data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**showTask** is a listener function, which listens to an onClick event. I don't know why I am getting a NullPointerException for **findViewById(R.id.listview)**.

Btw, I am a newbie to Android, that's why I am not sure whether I am missing something or not.

**EDIT**:
I have 2 layouts, activity_main.xml has some buttons. Whenever someone clicks those buttons showTask method is called.

DaysList is the activity associated with the activity_main.xml as it is my first page of the application. That's why I cannot change it with taskview.xml.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#F44336"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".DaysList">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:src="@drawable/mon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#F44336"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingBottom="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="15sp"
            android:paddingLeft="25sp"
            android:text="Monday"
            android:textColor="#E8F5E9"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:onClick="showTask"/>
    </LinearLayout>


Thanks!!
```

Comment: Why are you wasting your time dear. Just see your `activity_main` xml has `listview`?? You have defined wrong `XML` change your xml with `taskview.xml`

Comment: You have to set the R.layout.taskview in onCreate, since listview is in that xml file

Answer (score 2):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.taskview);
```

because you are setting wrong xml file.  And use this in your `onCreate` method

Comment: add your R.layout.activity_main

Comment: you can add listview in your activity_main and onclick listener set its visibility

Comment: yes 1) adjust visibilty 2) create another activity on your click

Answer (score 2):

get your listView in onCreate method and you haven't called showTask as well

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); 
    showTask();          
}
```

and remove it from the showTask method

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taskview); 

    listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);          
}
```

Comment: I had put listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); in onCreate, and tried but still it was throwing NPE.

Comment: Hey try the updated answer, as I found the error that your listview is in taskview.xml class and you are inserting activity_main class.

Answer (score 0):

Your Listview is in taskview.xml

So use `setContentView(R.layout.taskview);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the view parameter given in showTask method to find your id
Something like this

```
listView= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```